# integral of a continuous function bounded. Prove function is identically zero.

Tags: analysis

Let ${\rm f}:{\mathbb R}^{k} \to {\mathbb R}$ be a continuous function. Assume that for any $a > 0$ and any $k$-cell $Q_{a}$ of side length $a$ $\left(~\mbox{and therefore volume}\ a^{k}\right)$ we have

$\displaystyle{%
\left\vert\,\int_Q {\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x\,\right\vert\le a^{2k} }$

Prove that $f$ is identically $0$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts or work to show where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that if $Q_a$ is centered at $x_0$ then $$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{1}{a^k} \int_{Q_a} f(x) \, dx = f(x_0).$$ Your hypothesis implies that this limit is zero.

Comment: Can you explain why the fact is true? Thank you!